# Is Running of Tomcat in just local Possible?

Tags: tomcat, server, tomcat8

I need a running Tomcat on server but, It cannot take a request from network. When I enter the Server Gui, I can connect Web Gui in the tomcat server.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could configure tomcat to listen only on the loopback interface:

for example:
in server.xml configuration file, search for the Connector tag and 
set the address attribute to the local loopback ip address

```
<Connector address="127.0.0.1" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ...
```